# How to properly spy on an Activity

Tags: android, mockito

Mockito creates a proxy instance when some thing is spied on. Now, is there any way to forward setters that are then executed on that proxy instance to the real instance that sits behind it?

*Rationale:* I have an object instance that I do not have completely under my control, i.e. an Android activity. I can give most parts of my app the proxied version and that runs fine as is, **but** because I need to create the spy / proxy very early during the creation phase of the activity, it is not yet fully instantiated, e.g. the base context is not attached. This happens on the proxy instance and is of course not used by the activity instance itself (which refers to itself via `Activity.this`). The end result is that this leads to all kinds of crashes because resource resolving happens via this base context, so the internal Fragment machinery throws NPEs and more.

Here is some code:

```
public class CustomAndroidJUnitRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    @Override
    public Activity newActivity(ClassLoader cl, String className, Intent intent)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Activity activity = super.newActivity(cl, className, intent);
        return maybeStubSomeDelegate(activity);
    }

    private Activity maybeStubSomeDelegate(Activity activity) {
        if (!(activity instanceof SomeDelegate)) {
            return activity;
        }
        Activity spiedActivity = spy(activity);
        doReturn(SomeDelegateMock.getInstance())
            .when((SomeDelegate) spiedActivity)
            .getDelegate();
        return spiedActivity;
    }
}
```

I'm clueless - any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use espresso : https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/ So you can control the activity also.

Comment: I am already using Espresso, this has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: is adding an @VisibleForTesting setDelegate() method to your activity out of the question?  I feel that any approach that involves injecting spies of the Activity will always have some edge case where it will not work.

Comment: Well, I guess this is something that I have to consider, *sigh*.

Comment: Didn't really read the entire question, but isn't Mockito's thenCallRealMethod() what you want?

Comment: @Jozua Yes and I believe this is what `Mockito.spy()` already does anyways, because it is a shorthand for `Mockito.mock(myInstance.getClass(), withSettings().spiedInstance(myInstance).defaultAnswer(Mockito.CALL_REAL_METHODS));`

Comment: Are you spying on the Activity you're testing? From a higher point of view, doesn't that affect your test results? A solution from a different angel would be not spying on your subject, but wrap whatever "dependency" code inside of it in an object, then mock that object to do or not do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using:

android Test Support library's
  [SingleActivityFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/intercepting/SingleActivityFactory),
  [ActivityTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule)
and Mockito's
  [spy()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy-java.lang.Class-)

```
dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.21.0'
}
```

### Outline:

inject the spied instance inside SingleActivityFactory's implementation

### Code:

```
public class MainActivityTest {
    MainActivity subject;

    SingleActivityFactory<MainActivity> activityFactory = new SingleActivityFactory<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class) {
        @Override
        protected MainActivity create(Intent intent) {
            subject = spy(getActivityClassToIntercept());
            return subject;
        }
    };

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> testRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(activityFactory, true, true);

    @Test
    public void activity_isBeingSpied() {
        verify(subject).setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Comment: Very nice! This must be new!

Comment: After playing around a bit,
I've come to the conclusion that you have to be extra careful when spying on the activity like this (assuming you will be interacting with the UI),
since you essentially bypass Espresso's built-in sync mechanisms with the UI.

So, you have to delay your test (i.e. Thread.sleep()) to let the UI finish it's thing and catch up to the test,
and only afterwards you should get info from the spy

Comment: Noe that now ActivityTestRule is deprecated, and the official android test lib doesn't appear to offer similar functionality to create from a factory an activity that you can spy unfortunately.  Docs suggest  ActivityScenario or ActivityScenarioRule  but I haven't been able to find a way to spy an activity using either yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Robolectric to create your own proxy (or as Robolectric calls them "Shadows") to your activity,

When you create the proxy you can create your own setters that can trigger the real object methods,

How to create a shadow example:

```
@Implements(Bitmap.class)
public class MyShadowBitmap {

@RealObject private Bitmap realBitmap;
private int bitmapQuality = -1;

@Implementation
public boolean compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream) {
  bitmapQuality = quality;
  return realBitmap.compress(format, quality, stream);
}

public int getQuality() {
  return bitmapQuality;
}
}
}
```

when the @RealObject is your real instance,

To use this shadow using Robolectric test runner define a new test class as follows:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(shadows = MyShadowBitmap.class)
public class MyTestClass {}
```

To pull the current shadow instance use the method:

```
shadowOf()
```

And in any case, here is s link to Robolectric:

http://robolectric.org/custom-shadows/

Comment: This might be useful for unit testing, but I was actually talking about instrumentation testing :)

Comment: Also useful for instrumentation tests (assuming you don't want them running on the device\emulator)