# How to spy on an activity

Tags: android

In my instrumentation/unit test, I'd like to verify that an Activity's method is called in `onCreate` (when app is launched AND while it is already open) and `onNewIntent`.

I've tried `ActivityTestRule`, but I ran into two problems:

- I have to invoke `onNewIntent` on the ui thread, because it modifies the view. So I'm forced to do something like `Thread.sleep` to wait for the task to finish
- It's impossible to spy the activity in the rule without hacking the library

I've also looked into Robolectric, but it seems like it has a reputation for being flaky and slow.

Any suggestions for possible approaches with Espresso or Mockito or a different testing framework?

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495226/how-to-properly-spy-on-an-activity